# Don't know how to write the a code for func printStatsFor(number1 : Int, number2 : Int, number3 : Int)

Tags: swift, xcode, function, int, printf

### Having difficulty with an assignment

Hello, I've received an assignment that asks me to do write a fuct code for the following tasks:

> This function should take in 3 numbers and print the following:
>
> 1. sum of the three numbers
> 2. average of the three numbers
> 3. product of the three numbers
> 4. smallest of the three numbers
> 5. largest of the three numbers
>
> and start with the following line:
>
> `func printStatsFor(number1 : Int, number2 : Int, number3 : Int) {`

I've been trying for several hours, and I can't make it work. I've looked all over the internet and tried several things. I keep adding clips of code from the web and referring back to any manual I can find, however, the issues aren't resolved and the code just seems to get MORE complex and less cohesive. Here is the latest iteration:

```
func printStatsFor(number1 : Int, number2 : Int, number3 : Int) -> Int {

    print("Enter first number")
    var number1 = readLine ()!
    print("Enter second number")
    var number2 = readLine ()!
    print("Enter third number")
    var number3 = readLine ()!
    let totalNum = 3

    var theSum = ((number1 + number2 + number3))
    var intSum = Int(theSum) ?? 0
    var theAverage = ((intSum) / 3)
    var theProduct = ((number1 * number2 * number3))

    if number1 < number2 ; number3 {
        let number1 = smallestInt
    }
    if number2 < number3 ; number1 {
        var number2 = smallestInt
    }
    if number3 < number1 ; number2 {
        var number3 = smallestInt
       }
    if number1 > number2 ; number3 {
        var number1 = biggesttInt
    }
    if number2 > number3 ; number1 {
        var number2 = biggestInt
    }
    if number3 > number1 ; number2 {
        var number3 = biggestInt
       }
    print("The Sum")
    print(theSum)
    print("The Average")
    print(theAverage)
    print("The Product")
    print(theProduct)
    print("The Smallest")
    print(theSmallest)
    print("The Largest")
    print(theLargest)

}
printStatsFor(number1 : Int, number2 : Int, number3 : Int)
```

Any advice would be a lifesaver. I'm doing my college classes remotely and usually I would meet with my professor, but that's no longer possible, and we aren't even in the same time zone. If there is a website I can refer to  as a guide if you wouldn't mind pointing me in that direction I'd be ever so grateful. I cannot, for the love of me, figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I must be missing some key information.

Comment: Instead of asking for "any advice", you should [edit] your question so that it asks _one specific question_. At the moment, your question needs more focus.

Comment: The whole point of this function having the 3 integer params `number1`, `number2` and `number3` is for their values to be *passed in* by the caller. As you currently have it, this function is fetching those values itself from the command line using `readLine()`. You should extract that code out, and pass the values in as arguments to the parameters of the function.

Comment: If you found my solution below helpful, press the checkmark to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing way too much work. Let's start with the function declaration:

```
func printStatsFor(number1: Int, number2: Int, number3: Int) {

}
```

We see there are 3 parameters (`number1, number2, number3`) passed *into* the function. That means that when the function is called, somebody *already picked* the numbers and is telling you what they are. For example, another part of the code might say `printStatsFor(number1: 2, number 2: 5, number3: 14)`, and then expect this to be printed to the console:

```
21
7
140
2
14
```

Now your job is to write what goes in the function body (in between the curly brackets). The problem asks you to print to the console 5 statistics, so first calculate them and the print:

```
let sum = number1 + number2 + number3
print(sum)
let average = sum / 3
print(average)
...
```

Also, here's a hint for calculating the min and max: [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1540516-min).

That's it!

You have a mistake in your code right now:  `if number1 < number2 ; number3` is not valid syntax in Swift. If you want to compare two numbers, you can say `if number1 < number2`, but you can't just throw in another variable too. See my hint above for finding the min and the max in a cleaner way.